# Using a dictionary to dynamically pass values to an ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to pass a  `Dictionary<string, string>` to `Html.ActionLink()`?

#### My Dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "serviceId", "2342" } }
```

I tried doing this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Text here", "Action","Controller", myDictionary, null)
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Text here", 
    "Action", 
    "Controller", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(myDictionary), 
    null
) %>
```

where `myDictionary` should be an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: And, if you're going to do this a lot, you can create an HTML Helper for it too.

Comment: @Remus, this HTML helper already exists: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx so why create another one? I guess you don't like the `new RouteValueDictionary` part. Me neither :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.... create an overload that looks like this:  

public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
 this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
 string linkText,
 string actionName,
 string controllerName,
 IDictionary<string, Object> routeValues
)

Especially if you don't have htmlAttributes every time.